# Use wifi to find location instead of gps, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, geolocation

I am using navigator.geolcation like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            displayBestPosition, 
            displayError,
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
        );
```

I'm accessing it on my android device browser so its using my gps. However, when I am inside and I keep getting timeouts I'd like to switch from gps to getting the location from wifi. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: enableHighAccuracy: false will remove the demand for the GPS, though it still might get used if needed.

Comment: I actually do this after it times out twice. I have another call to getCurrentPosisiont where enableHighAccuracy is false. It still tries to access my gps unfortunately. :/

Comment: you don't have explicit control over how the phone gets the location, so im guessing your wifi alone is not enough for it to be confident.

Comment: hmm that's unfortunate, do you know if me having this first call with enableHighAccuracy to high affects my second call where enableHighAccuracy is false?

Comment: i know that it should not...

Comment: can you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition instead?

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CJMbk/)

```
<head>
<script>
var myip;
function callback(data) {
    alert(data.city);
}
function request_location() {
    var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var oScript = document.createElement("script");
    oScript.type = "text/javascript";
    oScript.src = "http://ip-api.com/json/" + myip + "?callback=callback";
    oHead.appendChild(oScript);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip" onload="request_location();"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: When I check the coordinates based of ip it was off by a couple of miles. This distance is too great for my needs.

Comment: Well there's no way to get more accurate without using GPS